# Retrieve items from an observable collection at specific indexes

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I am trying to retrieve items at specific index locations from an ObservableCollection. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there are properties `Item` and `Items`.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
string item1;
item1 _strings.Item[0];
item1 _strings.Items[0];
```

When I use `Item`, I get:

> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And when I use `Items`, I get:

> Cannot access protected member 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Items' via a qualifier of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'; the qualifier must be of type 'Model.MyStringCollection' (or derived from it)

I just cannot see what I am doing wrong here, right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When any class has an indexed property it gets labeled as and `Item` property. This allows referencing the indexer property with `object[index]` syntax, not `object.Item[index]` syntax. This is due to the fact that the property needs a name, and is a property defined as

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get 
    {
        //...
    }
    set        
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

EDIT: See [this article on indexer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx) for further reading

Answer (score 3):

You just call it like:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
...

string item1 = _strings[0];
```

But you need to add to the collection first!

Answer (score -2):

The right syntax is this:

```
_strings.Item(0);
```

not this

```
_strings.Item[0];
```

The call to `Item()` or `Items()` is actually a method call. The indexer operator is not needed.

Comment: I tried that already. It gives me the following error: `'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Actually now I noticed item1, what are you trying to do with it? Do you want to write: item1 = _strings.Item(0) ?